# Problema al instalar composer en ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer

Intenté instalar composer a través del comando PHP como se dice en el sitio getcomposer,
pero el bash arroja un error:

**php: orden no encontrada**

Instalé php a través del instalador de XAMPP.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0):

yo pude solucionar el mismo problema para instalar composer haciendo lo siguiente:

- sudo su
- apt-get install curl
- apt-get install mcrypt php-json php-cli
- cd /usr/local/bin
- php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
- php composer-setup.php
- php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
- mv composer.phar composer

Con esto me funcionó. Espero que te sirva